# Exception when having Object type field in JPA @Entity: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a JPA object that has field like that:

```
@Column(name = "check_close")
private Object check_close;
```

and the start I'm getting

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of columns: rf.dom.billing.model.billing.TransactionRegistry.check_close type: object
```

Why the error is about the wrong number of columns? Shouldn't it point to the wront type used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing type to some more valuable type like `String` made this error be never thrown, however, it is still intriguing for me why the error message was unrelated to the useless of `Object` type as JPA Entity field.